# making regex capture group optional in url for a tornado app

Tags: python, regex, tornado

I want to make the regex capture group in a url optional. i.e. I want to handle both `example.com/url` and also `example.com/url/something` by a single handler.

I can use `(r'/0(/?\w*)', Handler)`, but is that the right way to do it? If I go by this way, then I need to have a if-else block to see whether the requested url is /0 or /0/something.

Ideally, I would like something like this. `(r'/0', r'/0/(\w+)' Handler)`. A handler which can accept two different url types and work on it. And in handler implementation, I would see if the parameter input to the handler is None, then I would display /0 page and consider user has submitted an answer otherwise.

Here is the reason why I want to do this. I am building a simple quiz app, where question will rendered by `example.com/0` url and user will submit his answer as `example.com/0/answer`. I have 100 questions. In that case if I am handling questions and answers separately, then I would have 200 handlers against 100 handlers.

Or is this a bad design overall? Instead of creating 100 handlers, I have to use if-else blocks. Any suggestions?

PS: I don't want to change url formats. i.e. questions always will be displayed on `example.com/0` (and not `example.com/0/`) and user will submit his answers as `example.com/0/answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use HTTP methods and a single handler:

```
class QuestionHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        # Display the question

    def post(self, id):
        # Validates the answer
        answer = self.get_argument('answer')

application = Application([
    (r'/(\d+)', QuestionHandler),
])
```

But if you insist on using a separate handlers:

```
class QuestionHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        # Display the question

class AnswerHandler(RequestHandler):
    def post(self, id):
        # Validates the answer
        answer = self.get_argument('answer')

application = Application([
    (r'/(\d+)', QuestionHandler),
    (r'/(\d+)/answer', AnswerHandler),
])
```

Comment: ^but I would end up having 100 if-else blocks in first case. Is that better idea against 100 handlers? How so?

Comment: @avi: Why would you ever have 100 of either?

Comment: because I have 100 different questions. So for each of them to handle, wouldn't I need them?

Comment: @avi: No, that's what a database is for.

Comment: damn, how come I didn't think of database earlier x_x, makes everything so simple. Thank you very much!